# Display all reviews on one page

Tags: magento-1.9, review

I need display all approved reviews on one CMS page.

I tried below code but not working .

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach ($collection as $product){
    //var_dump($product);
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($product->getData('entity_id'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$review_collection = Mage::getModel('review/review')
->getResourceCollection()
->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
->setDateOrder()
->addRateVotes();

foreach($review_collection as $review){


    //echo "<pre>";
    echo $review['detail'];   //Here you can get the review wrote by customer
    //exit;



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the entity filter `addEntityFilter`:

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

    $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_product')->getCollection()
        ->addEntityFilter('product', $product->getEntityId())

     foreach($summaryData as $review)
         {
          //print_r($summaryData);
        var_dump($review->getData());
         }


}
```

Comment: not working unfortunately

Comment: @yavonz15 update the code try it

Comment: it does not work again

Comment: @yavonz15 update the code now tested too..

Answer (score 0):

Call a phtml file in cms page and put below code in this file:

```
$_reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')
->getResourceCollection()
->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
->setDateOrder()
->addRateVotes();

foreach($_reviews as $review){
// load the product for the corresponding review if You need to display product information
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($review->getData('entity_pk_value'));
$j=0;
$cumulative = 0;
foreach( $review->getRatingVotes() as $vote ) {
$cumulative +=$vote->getPercent();
$j++;
}
$finalPercentage = 0;
if ($cumulative != 0){
$finalPercentage = ($cumulative/$j);
}
}//close the foreach
?>
```

Please let me know if you have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Complete code

```
 <?php 

    $review_collection = Mage::getModel('review/review')
    ->getResourceCollection()
    ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
    ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
    ->setDateOrder()
    ->addRateVotes();
     ?>

<?php foreach($review_collection as $review): ?>

<div class='review-single col-md-12'>
<div class="box-review-single">
    <p id="title-review">
        <?php echo $review['title'];  ?>
    </p>
    <p id="detail-review">
        <?php echo $review['detail'];  ?>
    </p>
    <p id="nick-review">
        <?php echo $review['nickname'];  ?>
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```