# Display reviews in home page magento 2

Tags: magento2, review

I found this [Display all Reviews On a Single CMS page in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198040/display-all-reviews-on-a-single-cms-page-in-magento-2)  and i tried this code in block cms and i have data in review detail but there is nothing shown so why is't empty and can any one help me in this issue thanks in advance[image]

here is the code display.phtml 
i created a module with routes and simple controller and block

Comment: Can  you  please your code?

Comment: I have tried code from the link and it is working fine. Could you post how you done this ?

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: i updated my post

Comment: I just copied the code in the article and put it in display.phtml under templates

Comment: my layout <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="2columns-right">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magenticians\Review\Block\Display" name="hello" template="display.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: $reviewsCollection = $_reviewsColFactory->create()
    ->addStoreFilter($_storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId())
    ->addStatusFilter(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
    ->setDateOrder();

foreach($reviewsCollection as $review):?>
    <div class='review-single col-md-12'>
        <div class="box-review-single">
            <p id="title-review">
                <?php echo $review['title'];  ?>
            </p>
            <p id="nick-review">
                <?php echo $review['nickname'];  ?>